# The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

Trying to build a docker image using Dockerfile it executes correctly layer by layer but once it reaches pip requirements layer it gives traceback error. After searching found out setting environment path will fix the problem but still it gives same error.

Tried same in ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 works fine.But when trying to create image in ubuntu server (lamb) facing this issue.
Running ubuntu server OS in Virtual Box.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
 FROM python:2
 RUN mkdir /app
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN apt-get update
 RUN apt-get install -y swig
 RUN apt-get install -y python-dev
 RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev
 COPY . /app/
 RUN export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

**Building Docker image:**

```
Step 1/13 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
  ---> a06c3a7d3393
 Step 2/13 : FROM python:2.7-slim
  ---> e1e8909cd647
 Step 3/13 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 90810681a80b
Step 4/13 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d4bb0a65e78
Step 5/13 : RUN apt-get install -y swig
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e58beadc9492
Step 6/13 : RUN apt-get install -y python-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87eb4aa77601
Step 7/13 : RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed7cd728dce6
Step 8/13 : COPY . /app
 ---> 991b213ee62a
Step 9/13 : ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/bin/python"
 ---> Running in 2a52a53a2190
Removing intermediate container 2a52a53a2190
 ---> 21a5000cb6cc
Step 10/13 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 7fa6749748ca
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import logging
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
from _weakref import (
ImportError cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements1.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: This isn't a docker problem it's a python import problem, I'd amend your tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIP (Python) : ImportError: cannot import name \_remove\_dead\_weakref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166873/pip-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-remove-dead-weakref)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ImportError+cannot+import+name+_remove_dead_weakref

Comment: Especially see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50455931/7976758. I suspect your Dockerfile COPY an entire virtualenv which you shouldn't do — virtualenvs are not portable.

Comment: Thanks but none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put each shell command in a separate RUN. It causes them to run in separate shells and environment variables from earlier shells don't affect later ones since every process has its own environment.

```
RUN export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python \
 && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Alternatively you could use temporary assignment syntax to set the variable and call pip in one command:

```
RUN PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Split RUN statements create unnecessary extra layers which leads to overly large images. Standard practice in Dockerfiles is to merge related RUNs into one large command with backslashes. With apt-get, it's a good idea to also [erase apt's cache files at the end](https://hackernoon.com/tips-to-reduce-docker-image-sizes-876095da3b34) so they don't become part of the layer.

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
        swig \
        python-dev \
        libssl-dev \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

By the way, FROM lines don't combine. When you write two of them the second one wins and the first is ignored.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM python:2
```

You may think you need to pick an OS and add python on top, but that's not how Docker images work. The python:2 image already has an OS layer underneath. Remember, Docker images are self-contained bundles. When you pull in python:2 you get not just the Python interpreter but also *all of its dependencies*.

- [python:2](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/00dfb8462f6b3fca152d46b20c0d3b70e8c7ff5b/2.7/stretch/Dockerfile) has `FROM buildpack-deps:stretch`.
- [buildpack-deps:stretch](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/ff09b5c5288f4643056bd7938268d749e9f8a2db/stretch/Dockerfile) has `FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-scm`.
- [buildpack-deps:stretch-scm](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/1845b3f918f69b4c97912b0d4d68a5658458e84f/stretch/scm/Dockerfile) has `FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-curl`.
- [buildpack-deps:stretch-curl](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/b0fc01aa5e3aed6820d8fed6f3301e0542fbeb36/stretch/curl/Dockerfile) has `FROM debian:stretch`.

Ah, there it is. Debian is the ultimate base image.