# I can't find the code of a Ruby web application

Tags: python, php, ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm super new to web development, but not new to programming as a whole. I'm extremely confused by this application which I was pulled into fixing because the person who normally does it can't anymore.

This may be a silly question, but I can't find the code or any HTML that contains the actual web pages. In the main folder, `~/myapp`, there contains:

```
- README.txt
- build
- env
    - bin
    - include
    - lib
    - local
    - man
    - passenger_wsgi.py
    - passenger_wsgi.pyc
    - pip-selfcheck.json
    - public
        - favicon.gif
        - favicon.ico
    - quickstart.html
    - sd.html
    - tmp
- error.log
- favicon.gif
- favicon.ico
- get-pip.py
- phpinfo.php
- pylibs
- quickstart.html
- sd.log
- myapp_flask
```

### Observations:

- `env/bin/`, `env/include/`, and `env/lib/` all have what appear to be versions of python in them.
- `env/local/` contains its own `bin/`, `include/`, and `lib/` directories that contain the exact same thing as the others.
- tmp contains the standard `restart.txt` used for Apache rails applications. (Note: `touch`ing this does restart the server, so this `env/` directory is linked to the application itself.).

### Questions:

- Does anyone recognize this file structure? What application type is it? Php? Rails? Something else?
- Does anyone know where I could look for the code that contains the actual web page? This is a full-fledged, live webpage that people have been using for a while, but I can't find the html (not even for the homepage). I've been searching for days, so I know I'm going about this wrong.

### Additional notes:

This error occurs when I restart the web application with `touch tmp/restart.txt/`

```
Web application could not be started
An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
Raw process output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

both `quickstart.html` contents are identical:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>DreamHost</title>
        <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dreamhost.com/wp-content/themes/dreamhost/style.css" />
</head>
<body id="domains">
        <div class="w1">
                <div class="w2">
                        <div id="wrapper">
                                <div id="header">
                                        <strong class="comingsoon-logo"><a href="http://www.dreamhost.com/">DreamHost Imagine the Web, Your Way</a></strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="main" style="padding-bottom: 24px">
                                        <h1>sendsomething.net Coming Soon!</h1>
                                        <div class="holder">
                                                <div class="content">
                                                        <p>The DreamHost customer who owns sendsomething.net has not yet uploaded their website or has chosen to leave this holding page active.</p>
                                                        <p>If you are the owner of this domain, you'll find your login information contained within the emails sent to you when your account was activated. Once logged in, you'll be able to delete this page (quickstart.html) and upload your new site.</p>
                                                        <p>Here are some helpful links for getting started:</p>
                                                        <p>
                                                                <a href="https://panel.dreamhost.com/"><img src="http://images.dreamhost.com/btn-orange-webpanel.png" alt="DreamHost Web Panel" title="DreamHost Web Panel" /></a>
                                                                <a href="http://wiki.dreamhost.com/"><img src="http://images.dreamhost.com/btn-blue-wiki.png" alt="DreamHost Wiki" title="DreamHost Wiki" /></a>
                                                                <a href="http://discussion.dreamhost.com/"><img src="http://images.dreamhost.com/btn-green-discussion.png" alt="DreamHost Discussion Forum" title="DreamHost Discussion Forum" /></a>
                                                        </p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for your time and assistance!

### Edit:

Per request of answerer, Here are the contents of `~/myapp/myapp_flask/`:

```
- .hg
- .hgignore
- backup_config.ini
- backup_db
- db_backups
- db_repo
- dbmanage.py
- doc
- dump.sql
- example_backup_config.ini
- instance
- migrate_dbs.py
- new.db
- new_bkp.db
- requirements.txt
- restored.db
- restored.dbe
- myapp
    - __init__.py
    - __init__.py.orig
    - __init__.pyc
    - app.py
    - app.pyc
    - forms.py
    - forms.pyc
    - helpers.py
    - helpers.pyc
    - static
    - templates
    - user.py
    - user.pyc
    - views.py
    - views.pyc
- myapp.wsgi
- teste.db
- webfaction.db
```

Comment: What does `quickstart.html` have in it? Does this shed any light as to what you are looking at. The `phpinfo.php` file is concerning especially if it's just `<?php phpinfo();` because that tells all the configurations for a PHP server.

Comment: `.py` are Python files. You could just ask the person who maintained it before

Comment: The previous maintainer is unavailable, sadly. I've added the contents of `quickstart.html` to the question body.

Comment: What does this application actually *do*? As in should it have a lot of code and doesn't? Can you pull the full directory with files from the server itself (assuming it's still running), because maybe the repo you have is bad or it's in a different branch etc

Comment: Is there anything in the `myapp_flask` file or folder? Perhaps this is a [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) project? At first glance, it doesn't look like a Rails type of project to me, though Passenger is usually what I see when it comes to Rails projects. [It looks like](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/) Passenger can work with Python as well. Flask projects might have less structure than something like Rails or Laravel, so it might be hard to recognize at first glance (if this is indeed a Flask project).

Comment: Also the `wsgi` part of the `passenger_wsgi.py` file (and the `.py` file endings, like @brombeer [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660906/i-cant-find-the-code-of-a-ruby-web-application#comment117839584_66660906) earlier) seem to give away that this is primarily a Python-based project. If you open the contents of the `myapp_flask` file/folder, I wonder if you'll find more evidence that this could be a Flask project (e.g., maybe a Flask-related `import` statement). Also, the `phpinfo.php` file might have been used for testing something else unrelated, because that is a PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This might not be a complete answer, but it might be a starting place for one.

Possibly in answer to your first question, and based on the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660906/i-cant-find-the-code-of-a-ruby-web-application#comment117848054_66660906) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660906/i-cant-find-the-code-of-a-ruby-web-application#comment117848088_66660906) [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660906/i-cant-find-the-code-of-a-ruby-web-application#comment117839584_66660906), this project looks to me like it might be a [Flask web application](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). Flask is a Python [microframework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/foreword/#what-does-micro-mean) that can be used to build simple or complex web applications. I'm guessing this based on the following observations:

1. The `passenger_wsgi.py` file
2. The observation of the files ending in `.py` [made by brombeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8034901/brombeer) in the comments
3. The item at the bottom of your application structure list called `myapp_flask`

As far as the `passenger_wsgi.py` file, Passenger is a [web application server](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/python/fundamental_concepts.html) used to run web applications written in [things like Python, Ruby, or Node.js](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/).

As far as brombeer's observation about the file extensions, files that end in `.py` are [typically Python files](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#command-line).

As far as that `myapp_flask` item, if there are contents inside this file or folder, I wonder if it might contain the main web application code. Would it be possible to check that file or folder to see if it contains application code? Warning: It might contain sensitive data (e.g., passwords, secrets, or keys), so I don't know if it should be posted in your original post above.

So, I guess I touched on your second main question in that earlier response: you might be able to find the main web application code in the `myapp_flask` item. If nothing is there, however, you might be able to determine where the main application code is by looking at the contents of your `passenger_wsgi.py`.

[In this example `passenger_wsgi.py` file](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/wsgi_spec.html) in the Passenger documentation, it shows how an example (Django, in that case) application might be referred to in this type of file. If you open your `passenger_wsgi.py` in a text editor, it might a show a reference to the main application code on a line that contains the term `application =` (or something similar), like in the earlier example. Maybe this could help you know what the name of the application might be.

Then, you could possibly use `grep` to search for the application name in your file structure, if `grep` is available on your system. Maybe using a search command like: `grep -r 'application-name' *`. That might give you more clues as to where the main application code is located.

As far as the additional note about your `ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref` error, I don't know if it's similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49166873/1167750) from the past. I would recommend caution, however, before changing up your Python 2 related setup based on answers in that other question thread, unless you are alright with whatever might happen along the way. I haven't tried out the answers myself from that thread.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer! Per your request, I've posted the contents of `myapp_flask`. Inside, I notice the `myapp_flask/myapp/templates/` dir has some of the html for the webpage I've been looking for! Does it still look like a flask project to you?

Comment: @retrovius No problem about that! Thank you for adding that info! It still looks like a Flask project to me, but to be sure on your side, I would recommend opening up the `myapp_flask/myapp/app.py` file in a text editor and checking to see if there is anything that says "Flask" in it (especially in the "imports" area at the top). You might not want to post the contents of that file to your original question post, though, unless you are sure that there are no secrets in that file (like configuration related secrets, passwords, keys, etc.).

Comment: Excellent! There is a `from flask import Flask` line in `app.py`, indicating that it is a flask project. Thank you so much for your help! Now to debug the Passenger issue...

Comment: @retrovius I'm glad you had the opportunity to verify the existence of the `Flask` reference in the `app.py` file! No problem about the help! I'm glad to be of help! Sorry that there is more going on with the application, though. I hope you can find out what is going on with that Passenger issue at some point!